# How to return a Cumulative Value based on Criteria

Tags: sql

I have the following table and based on the MonthID I want to retrieve the Cumulative Value.  ie:  For InvoiceID 1 and MonthID 26, I want to add MonthID 24, 25 and 26 reportMonthVal.

**Table**

[image]

I would like to retrieve the following

**Results**

[image]

Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the cumulative sum window function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(t.reportmonthval) over (partition by t.invoiceid order by t.monthid) as ytdval
from t;
```

Answer (score 2):

use window function

```
select *, sum(Reportmonthval) over( partition by invoiceid order by monthid ) asYtval
from table_name
```